# make text in ion-select clickable

Tags: ionic2

The template:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label stacked>Select clickable option texts</ion-label>
  <ion-select>
    <ion-option value="opt1"><a (click)="myDetails()">Option one description<a> text</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

As you can see above, I want to make certain parts of the text in  clickable, like to show the definition. I am using toast to show the text. But I am unable to get my head around making part of the text actually clickable.

Is there a way?

Comment: When the select changes value you want to display a toast? Or when you click on an option in the alert window?

Comment: When I click on certain words in the alert window. Say one of the option reads "Option one description text". I want the word "text" be clickable, or long-clickable or whatever else that may work in <ion-option>.

I am basically working on a medical app and many of the terms are try, and displaying the whole text as an option won't work as <ion-option> wraps the text.

So I am thinking to make the technical terms; definition show as a Toast.